# html code for image is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
All other HTML code is displayed correctly except for image

This is my code for form.

<th>Content Type</th>
<td>
    <%= f.radio_button(:content_type, 'text') %> Text
    <%= f.radio_button(:content_type, 'HTML') %> HTML

</td>
(<img src="/home/prem/Desktop/a.jpg"  />)


    <% case section.content_type    
     when 'HTML' %>    
     <%= raw section.content %>
```

There is a problem in displaying HTML code for image . It works well some for all HTML tags except image. answer is welcome heartly

Comment: what rails have to do with your `img` tag? it is pure html.

Comment: image can be put in app/assets. how can i give the path of image so that <% = raw %> works?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image url is valid for a browser, that it's a valid URL, like http://yoursite.com/home/star.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will run it locally only, try one of these:

```
<img src="file://home/prem/Desktop/a.jpg"  />
```

or

```
<img src="file:///home/prem/Desktop/a.jpg"  />
```

On Windows,

```
<img src="file://C:/home/prem/Desktop/a.jpg"  />
```